# Different Arrowheads bend differently (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, arc

I have stumbled upon some weird behaviour regarding arcs and arrowheads.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \def\Rad{2cm}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
                            \draw[blue, thick] (0:\Rad) arc (0:360:\Rad);
                            \draw[orange,->]  (90:\Rad)    arc (90:90-170:\Rad);    
                            \draw[orange,-{Triangle[length=1mm, width=1mm]}] (90:\Rad) arc (90:90+170:\Rad);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

If you look closely at the outcome, one can notice that the orange arcs bend differently:
[image]

I would rather use the triangular arrowheads, but it is the one that bends differently than the actual circle, so I can not use it as it seems to be inaccurate.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is to also load `bending` to cure this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\def\Rad{2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \draw[blue, thick] (0:\Rad) arc (0:360:\Rad);
 \draw[orange,->]  (90:\Rad)    arc (90:90-170:\Rad);    
 \draw[orange,-{Triangle[length=1mm, width=1mm]}] (90:\Rad) arc (90:90+170:\Rad);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: pgfmanual p. 194-195

[image]

Comment: I'm glad there already exists a fix. Thank you!